# posting from html to php post with js ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

im new to js and ajax and need a little bit of help.
im trying to make cart quantity with js, after the user pressing the add_cart button I want to get the quantity of items the user wants and post it via php post, after pressing the button im getting 0 results from the post.

so here it goes:

```
$id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
$value = 1;
$list .= "<div id='single_product'>
          <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
          </br>
          <h3>$pro_title</h3>
          <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪ :מחיר</p>
          <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
          </br>
          <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button class='button_addCart' value='submit' onclick='javascript:post();' >הוסף לסל</button></a>
          <form name='f1' method='post' action='../index.php'>
            <input type='button' name='inc' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"$id\").value++;' value='+' />
            <input type='number' name='quan' style='width:25%;' id='$id' value='$value' min='1' />
            <input type='button' name='dec' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"$id\").value--;' value='-' /> 

            <script type ='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function post()
                {
                    var value=document.getElementById(\"$id\").value;

                    $.post('functions.php',{postname:value},
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $('#value').innerhtml(data);
                    });
                }
            </script>    
          </form>
         </div>" ;
```

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors are showing

Comment: How do you set `postname`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 
var valuee=document.getElementById(\"$id\").value;

Comment: Can you share functions.php?

Comment: Er, view the source on the outputted HTML. Is $id populated properly?

Comment: 'valuee'..? or 'value'

Comment: oops didn't noticed, changed back to value but the script still stops.
basicly, I want to send a post via js to the functions.php page (which is the same page as the js is in it) . I want to get the value from the form above the script (where id=$id and value=$value) and post it back to the page.
yes $id is populated but I want to get the $value not the $id
@drmarvelous

Comment: @ChrisMaggs comment above

Comment: I see this: `document.getElementById(\"$id\").value` which is looking for an element in the DOM with the id of whatever id you are passing. But i do not see an element with that same ID set. Can you please clarify?

Comment: this is a php while loop which posts this whole div one next to another. the purpose of the bottom piece of code is to control the quantity of the product for the user (which is set by js)
and heres the id

{<input type='number' name='quan' style='width:25%;' id='$id' value='$value' min='1' />}
@CodeGodie

Comment: regardless of it being populated by a php loop, the code `document.getElementById().value` will always look for DOM elements. If they are not created, then it will fail, because it will not find any elements.

Comment: I see where it is now. Let me continue inspecting

Comment: @CodeGodie im not even sure that the js script is correct, I used js maybe twice in my life before

Comment: i would really try to separate the js function from the PHP loop. You are just creating extra js functions in your DOM for no reason.

Comment: @CodeGodie
here is the whole functions.php page 
http://pastebin.com/vFKEcC4e
the posted code is in lines 296 - 320 ~

Comment: when you are sending that ajax post to your functions.php, what are you trying to do? is it just to update the cart's quantity for that product?

Comment: @CodeGodie im trying to get the post at line 48 (full functions.php in pastebin) im just trying to update the same qty=$qty value=$value field and afterwards put the $_POST from ajax into product quantity db.
oh, and is it legit to use 



<button class='button_addCart' value='submit' onclick='javascript:post();' >הוסף לסל</button></a>

on line 305

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here. One issue is that all this code (according to you) is inside a while loop; this means that for every iteration you are creating the same JavaScript which does the same function, thus loading the DOM with unnecessary script. Another problem is the HTML, it is badly parsed, one  example, you have a button that has its own function inside anchor links that have their own `href`. However, the biggest issue here is how it is all mangled up (its what they call "*spaghetti code*"). You need to separate things up in order to fix this. Try the MVC approach where you have the view that takes care of the parsing, and your functions file should act as the controller/model. I would do the following:

Your **functions.php** should be a class with different functions. One of those should be a function that retrieves the data from your database `get_products()`, turns it into an array, and stores it in a variable. This variable is then returned. For demonstration purposes I will just hard code an array:

```
//located in: app/functions.php

class Functions {
    function get_products() {
        $products_array = array(
            array(
                "id" => 1,
                "image" => "test.jpg",
                "fullprice" => 50,
                "price" => 40,
                "title" => "Some Name",
                "quantity" => 2,
            ),
            array(
                "id" => 2,
                "image" => "test2jpg",
                "fullprice" => 50,
                "price" => 40,
                "title" => "Some Name2",
                "quantity" => 1,
            )
        );
        return $products_array;
    }

    function update_cart(){
        return "cart updated";
    }
}

//the code below will be needed to execute AJAX
if (isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)) {
    $res = $funcs->$_GET['function']();
    return json_encode($res);
}
```

Your "**view**" should have anything you want to parse in the DOM. In this case, we are calling the function `get_products()` from your functions.php file, then parsing the array thourgh the page. Notice we are also linking the JavaScript file needed:

```
<!-- located in: app/product.php -->

<?php
include("functions.php");
$funcs = new Functions();
$products = $funcs->get_products();
?>

<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='products.js'></script>
<?php foreach ($products as $prod) { ?>
    <div class='product'>

        <a href='details.php?pro_id=<?= $prod["id"] ?>'>
            <img src='admin_area/product_images/<?= $prod["image"] ?>' width='100%' height='60%'/>
        </a>

        <h3><?= $prod["title"] ?>></h3>

        <p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> <?= $prod["fullprice"] ?> ₪ :מחיר</p>

        <p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> <?= $prod["price"] ?> ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>


        <input class="plus" type='button' value='+'/>
        <input class="quantity" type='number' value='<?= $prod["quantity"] ?>' min='1'/>
        <input class="minus" type='button' value='-'/>

        <input class="product_id" type="hidden" value="<?= $prod["id"] ?>"/>

        <button class='button_addCart' value='submit'>הוסף לסל</button>

    </div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Your **script** takes care of the functionality using jQuery:

```
//located in app/products.js

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".plus").click(function () {
        var $product_elem = $(this).closest(".product");
        var $quantity_elem = $product_elem.find(".quantity");
        $quantity_elem.val(parseInt($quantity_elem.val()) + 1);
    });

    $(".minus").click(function () {
        var $product_elem = $(this).closest(".product");
        var $quantity_elem = $product_elem.find(".quantity");
        $quantity_elem.val(parseInt($quantity_elem.val()) - 1);
    });

    $(".button_addCart").click(function () {
        var $product_elem = $(this).closest(".product");
        var quantity = $product_elem.find(".quantity").val();
        var id = $product_elem.find(".product_id").val();
        var postdata = {
            product_id: id,
            quantity: quantity
        };
        var url = "functions.php?function=update_cart";
        $.post(url, postdata, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.